# How can I check if a procedure exists in a package?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have packages with procedures, which are used in many places and in some places I need slightly different procedures, e.g. updating one more column.

I thought that I could create an extra package, which would contain some but not all of the procedures.

Is there any way to check in an `if` statement directly in scripts, that if there does not exist procedure in the extra package, to fall back on the standard package?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to obtain this information from the DBA_PROCEDURES view:

```
SELECT *
  FROM SYS.DBA_PROCEDURES
  WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE' AND
        OBJECT_NAME = '<your package name>' AND
        PROCEDURE_NAME = '<your procedure name>'
```

If this returns a row the procedure you're interested in exists in the package.  If you get a NO_DATA_FOUND exception it means the procedure doesn't exist in the package.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't the user that is querying SYS.DBA_PROCEDURES need special privileges? Maybe querying SYS.User_Objects requires less permissions?

```
select * from SYS.User_Objects where object_type = 'PACKAGE';
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also try

```
SELECT text FROM all_source WHERE name = 'PACKAGE' ORDER BY line;
```

Worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing your code as *normal* user you won't see SYS.DBA_PROCEDURES at all.

But you can do the same from user accessible table `user_procedures`:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM USER_PROCEDURES 
  WHERE OBJECT_TYPE='PACKAGE' AND 
        OBJECT_NAME ='<your package name>' AND 
        PROCEDURE_NAME = '<your procedure name>';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from USER_OBJECT where object_type='PACKAGE' AND OBJECT_NAME ='<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>'
```